# buttons and the links make an HTTP request to the file, which will filter the table created :

Tags: javascript, php, html

after enter 3 type of words (alphabetic numeric and alphanumeric in html file. on second page we need to create button and links which will take us to third page. if we click first button it should show us only alphabetic. second button should show only numeric.

someone please help!!

file second:

```
    $sentence = isset($_GET["phrase"]) ? $_GET["phrase"] : $_GET["phrase"];

    $w = transformer($sentence);


    $sentence = isset($_GET["filter"]) ? $_GET["filter"] : $_GET["filter"];

    $w = transformer($sentence);        
?>  

<table>
<tr>
<th>Word</th>
<th>Length</th>
<th>Type</th>
  <tr><td>
            <?php
  for ($x = 0; $x < count($w); $x++) {
      echo "$w[$x] <br>";
   }
      ?> </td>

        <td> <?php
  for ($x = 0; $x < count($w); $x++) {
      $length = strlen($w[$x]);
       echo "$length <br>";
   }
  ?> 
          </td>

       <td> <?php
  for ($x = 0; $x < count($w); $x++) {
      if (ctype_alpha($w[$x])) {
          echo "Alphabetic <br>";
      } else if(ctype_digit($w[$x])) {
          echo "Numeric <br>";
      } else {
          echo "Alphanumeric <br>";
      }
      }
  ?> 
          </td>
 </tr>        
 </tr>

 <?php

 function transformer($words){
    $w = explode(' ', $words);
    return $w;
 }

 function validation($words){

    if($words == null || $words == ""){
        echo "Submission will not proceed";
        return false;
    }

    else if(!is_numeric($words)){
        echo "Submission will proceed";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
  ?>


        <form action="PhraseFilter.php" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="phrase" value="<?php echo 
       $_POST["phrase"]?>"/>

            <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="TBD"/>

        <input type="submit" value="show alpha" 
   onclick="document.getElementById('filter').value = 'alphabetic';"/>

        <input type="submit" value="Show number" 
   onclick="document.getElementById('filter').value = 'numeric';" />

        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Second file

```
  $sentence = isset($_POST["phrase"]) ? $_POST["phrase"] : $_GET["phrase"];

    $w = transformer($sentence);

  $sentence = isset($_POST["filter"]) ? $_POST["filter"] : $_POST["filter"];

    $w = transformer($sentence);


   ?>   
   <table>
  <tr>
  <th>Word</th>
  <th>Length</th>
  <th>Type</th>
  <tr><td>

            <?php

  for ($x = 0; $x < count($w); $x++) {
      echo "$w[$x] <br>";
   }
      ?> </td>

        <td> <?php
  for ($x = 0; $x < count($w); $x++) {
      $length = strlen($w[$x]);
       echo "$length <br>";
   }
  ?> 
          </td>

       <td> <?php
  //for ($x = 0; $x < count($w); $x++)  {
      if ((ctype_alpha(substr($w[$x])){
      echo "Alphabetic <br>";
      } else if(ctype_digit(substr($w[$x])) {
          echo "Numeric <br>";
      } 

   //   }
  ?> 
          </td>
  </tr></tr>

   <?php

  function transformer($words){
    $w = explode(' ', $words);
    return $w;
  }

  // Validations
  function validation($words){
    // Validation if Empty
    if($words == null || $words == ""){
        echo "Submission will not proceed";
        return false;
    }
    // Validation if Valid Number
    else if(!is_numeric($words)){
        echo "Submission will proceed";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
  ?>
  <?php         
         ?>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: see [ctype_*](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ctype.php) functions.

Comment: ctype is working fine. i just dont know how to use button which will work as a filter to get: button 1: alphabet  button 2: numeric